# Protractor - unable to get URL title, webdriver just hangs

Tags: automation, protractor, ui-automation, browser-automation

just start messing around with Protractor for an upcoming project that may require front-end automation on an angular based website. After installing Protractor and running the given examples, tried to do a very simple test, like the following:

```
// test.js
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
    it('should have a title', function() {
      browser.get('http://www.google.co.uk');
      expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Google');
    });
  });
```

Problem is, the browser opens but then it just hangs until it closes with an error:

```
Failures:
1) Protractor Demo App should have a title
  Message:
    Failed: Cannot read property 'ver' of null
  Stack:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'ver' of null
        at executeAsyncScript_.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:716:56)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
        at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
    From: Task: Run it("should have a title") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/rubensantos/Documents/protractor/test.js:3:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rubensantos/Documents/protractor/test.js:2:1)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 4.056 seconds

[11:18:25] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[11:18:25] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[11:18:25] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[11:18:25] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

have no idea why this simple test does not work. Any help is welcome, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a great decision to disable Control Flow due to this [thread](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969) . In your `protractor.conf.js` file add `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` line. After it you should resolve `Promises` by yourself. For example your test will look like:

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
    it('should have a title', async function() {
      await browser.get('http://www.google.co.uk');
      expect(await browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Google');
    });
  });
```

Comment: thanks for the help, your suggestion solved it. But i also tried just adding browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); to my original code and it also worked. But i'll switch to your suggestion, thanks alot :)